# Meteor collection not being transformed

Tags: javascript, meteor

This code is failing to set the value of the field "class" to "wrongInput", even though the condition is evaluating to false where the block should be executed. 
The objective is to update the field "class"

**edited** and thus relaying on the reactiveness of meteor to update the expression {{class}} in on of the templates. How can this be done? Thanks

```js
meteor:PRIMARY> db.inputsCol.find({}).pretty();
{
 "_id" : "L9nrmjaoG6RAdxeqd",
 "element" : "input",
 "action" : "orderFood",
 "name" : "plate",
 "placeholder" : "Enter plate number",
 "valid" : "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}$",
 "value" : "KingKong",
 "class" : ""             <---- expected value is "wrongInput"
}

G.InputsCol = new Mongo.Collection('inputsCol', {
  transform: function (doc) {
    var patt = new RegExp(doc.valid, "g");
    if (!patt.test(doc.value)) {
       console.log('block run');
      doc.class = "wrongInput";  <---- This line ---------------------------
    }
    return doc;
  }
});

Template.index.helpers({
taskInputs: function () {
  var ready = Meteor.subscribe('inputsCol').ready();
  var data = InputsCol.find({});
  return {items: data, ready: ready};
  }
});
```

Comment: Collection transforms run only when the document is fetched. They don't modify the document in the database. To test the transform you'd need to do the following on either the client or the server: `console.log(G.InputsCol.findOne('L9nrmjaoG6RAdxeqd').class)`

Comment: written this command in the browser console gives the output string "wrongInput" as expected but then the mongo terminal shows no value for the "class" field. In addition, the rest of the code causes the block to be executed as stated "verified" by the console log in my edit but the line "doc.class = "wrongInput" is not causing the value to be "inserted" in the documents as verified at the mongo console. Even when the app first starts, the "block run" fires but no "wrongInput" string is inserted.

Comment: Yes, it's behaving as expected. See the first line of my previous comment. If you want it to be written back to the database, you'll need a hook instead.

Comment: Could you please give such answer with the hook? :) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transform is dynamically applied after a find/fetch. You are looking to modify the document in the database whenever the `value` field changes. There are a few ways to do that. One is just to make sure it gets updated properly in whatever code inserts or updates `InputsCol` documents. Alternatively, you can add a [hook](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) like so:

```
G.InputsCol = new Mongo.Collection('inputsCol');

G.InputsCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  var patt = new RegExp(doc.valid, 'g');
  if (!patt.test(doc.value))
    doc.class = 'wrongInput';
});

G.InputsCol.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
  if (_.contains(fieldNames, 'value')) {
    var patt = new RegExp(doc.valid, 'g');
    if (!patt.test(doc.value)) {
      modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
      modifier.$set.class = 'wrongInput';
    }
  }
});
```

Note the above code is untested, but the idea is that on insert or update of the collection, the document will self-modify its `class` field. You will need to `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks` in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks. I used the before.update alone and it updated the value of the field class to "wrongInput". Is the reactiveness behaviour still valid? because the {{class}} in the template which uses this value is not getting updated. thx

Comment: It should be. The hook should run as if your other code had modified the value. If it appears in your database but doesn't appear on the client, then maybe it's an unrelated issue.